# Pantalla blanca a correr un alert js en php

Tags: php, javascript, html

```
        <?php
    // Start the session
    session_start();
    ?>

    <html>
    <head>

      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

      <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/css.css">
      <title>Pregunta 1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form  method="POST" >
              <div id="login">
                <h4 class="text-center text-danger">Puntaje: <label class="text-dark"><?php echo $i=0; ?></label></h4>
                <h3 class="text-center text-white pt-4"><?php echo "Nombre del jugador: ".$_SESSION['nickname'];?></h3>
                <div class="container">
                    <div id="login-row" class="row justify-content-center align-items-center">
                        <div id="login-column" class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="login-box col-md-12">
                               <!-- <form id="login-form" class="form"  method="post"> -->
                                    <h3 class="text-center text-info">Primera Pregunta:</h3>
                                    <br><br>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label  class="text-info">Llamamos sujeto a:</label>

                                    </div>       
                                    <div >

                                       <center>                               
                                        <label  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" > <font SIZE=2>A.Expresiones escritas </font><input type="checkbox"  name="check1" value="a"  class="badgebox"><span class="badge">&check;</span></label>
                                        <label  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><font SIZE=2> B. Un individuo que habla</font><input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="b" class="badgebox"><span class="badge">&check;</span></label>
                                        <label  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><font SIZE=2> C. La persona, animal o cosa que realiza la acción del verbo</font><input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="c" class="badgebox"><span class="badge">&check;</span></label>
                                        <label class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"><font SIZE=2> D. Las palabras agudas</font><input type="checkbox"  name="check1" value="d" class="badgebox"><span class="badge">&check;</span></label>
                                    </center> 

                                </div>            
                                <center>            
                                    <button type="submit" name="inicio" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Volver al inicio</button>
                                    &emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&nbsp;
                                    <button type="submit" name="EnviarPrimera" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">&emsp;&emsp;Enviar&emsp;&emsp;</button>
                                </center>      

                            </form>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>




    </body>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['EnviarPrimera'])) {

        $res =  $_POST['check1'];


        if ($res == "c") {
          $i++;
          ?>

          <SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> 
          function alertFunc(){
            alert("Respuesta Correcta");
            location.href = "pregunta2.php?i=<?php echo $i?>";
        }
        window.onload=alertFunc;

        </SCRIPT> 
        <?php

    } else {
     ?>
     <SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> 
        alert("Respuesta incorrecta");
        location.href = "pregunta2.php?i=<?php echo $i?>";
    </SCRIPT> 
    <?php
}
}if (isset($_POST['inicio'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}

     ?>
     </html>
```

Al crear un formulario y mostrar la alerta en `Javascript`, me muestra la alerta("Respuesta Correcta"), pero la pantalla de fondo la muestra blanca, osea, necesito que al mostrar la alerta también me muestre el formulario que yo realice.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/207514/edit) tu pregunta para que el código se vea de manera adecuada, y añade más detalles del problema que se presenta

Comment: Que haz intentado?

Comment: de todo realmente, pero lo ultimo que intente es crear una función de javascript  y correrlo con "window.onload", pero todavía  me aparece el fondo blanco, ya intente dentro del cuerpo y nada.

Comment: haz intentado con un `confirm()` ??

Comment: ya lo intente y nada

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer esta bien el flujo de ejecucion:
1) alert("Respuesta incorrecta");
2) location.href = "pregunta2.php?i="; //-- una vez que hagas clic en aceptar.

Podrias usar el evento submit en javascript y asociarlo en tu formulario para hacer esta comprobacion y no refrescar la pagina, ademas si desdeas guardar en un base de datos po puedes hacer mediante ajax con tu metodo post.

Pon todo el codigo para ver en que te puedo ayudar

Comment: el programa no esta conectado en una bd ya que es un formulario sencillo, el codigo es el que lo publique

Answer (score 0):

Creo que debes buscar otro enfoque, tiene que ver con la función alert que se ejecuta en el hilo principal y bloquea el render del contenido, si lo guardas dentro de un setTimeout te funcionaria pero no es lo mejor. Aqui hay algo sobre eso [alert() block render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41985247/why-do-dom-updates-and-alert-execute-out-of-sequence-in-chrome)

[google docs](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/BlockingJS?hl=es-419)

```
setTimeout(() => {
  alert("Respuesta incorrecta");
}, 3000);
```